# Is there a R function for highlighting bold character while extracting into R

Tags: r

I have extracted the unstructured data from excel to R. Actually my excel data has bold sentence/characters at some place. I want the same to be extracted in R highlighting in bold. For example,

In excel. there is a paragraph that says, Contracts(this is in **bold**). But post extracting in R, these will not be in **bold**. Can we extract in bold as well

**[Code used]**

```
library(openxlsx)
filenames = list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$")
fullData = lapply(filenames, function(fil){ 
    sheetNames = names(loadWorkbook(fil)) 
    File_data = lapply(sheetNames, function(x){read.xlsx(fil,sheet = x)})
    names(File_data) = sheetNames 
    File_data
    }
  )
```

Comment: Can you share a sample excel content?

Comment: I cannot attach here. But the sample is                                                  
Terminology - First Row
Sale Price (INR) - Second Row
Ware house Plant 1  - Third Row                                                                  
Here the second row is in bold

Comment: Was this clear?

Comment: OK. Can you also share the code you used to extract and show the excel content in R?

Comment: library(openxlsx)
     filenames = list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$")

     fullData = lapply(filenames, function(fil){
     sheetNames = names(loadWorkbook(fil))
     File_data = lapply(sheetNames, function(x){read.xlsx(fil,sheet = x)})
     names(File_data) = sheetNames
     File_data
     })

     names(fullData) = filenames

Comment: Are you able to get it?

Comment: I got it well but still haven't figured out a solution yet.

Comment: :) OK, Even I trying to figure it out

Comment: I have posted your code in the question. Maybe someone else can also help.

Comment: its not possible to read formatting into R. You can manually bold things when plotting or if you use packages such as `flextable`